# Synthetic time series generation according to some distribution

Tags: time-series, probability, distribution

I'm trying to develop a change detection model that uses sliding windows. Given a time series with some features I've a sliding widows that analyses that time period and compares with a successive time window. If the distribution of data has changed than it is notified. Anyway, I don't have enough real data about my problem, so I need to generate some artificial time series but with different distributions, no matter what distributions, the important thing is that they are different, so that I can test when my model detects change in the data. How can I generate those data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think I have a simple way and you do not need to overthink it.

1. Take a Gaussian (Normal) distribution random number generator, it could even be just downloading a set from https://www.random.org/gaussian-distributions/
2. Multiply by the desired standard deviation, add the desired mean.
3. From a certain timestamp, change the standard deviation and mean to a new value to simulate the distribution change. This is the same as concatenating smaller sets with different mean and standard deviation.
4. See if/when your model detects it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Anyway, do you think that I should consider that because this should be a time series is not so "correct" to create a series with only values taken from a normal distribution? Should be values of a series correlated among themselves?

Comment: feel free to modify my proposal by adding the previous value, you probably have at least some idea on what your time series should look like..